# Run Time Error 1004 When Inserting Rows/Columns

Tags: vba, runtime-error

So I'm running into the lovely run time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error.

The bear of it is, half the time the code in VBA runs correctly with no problems, and the other half it falls on its face. The third line ("Mgmt.List.....") is run in a loop normally, but it has no problems messing up on me in this simple macro.

```
Sub whyyyy()
    Dim Mgmt As Worksheet
    Set Mgmt = Sheets("Mgmt MarginAnalysis")
    Mgmt.ListObjects("Table4").ListRows.Add (3)
End Sub
```

The line

```
Mgmt.ListObjects("Table4").ListRows.Add (3)
```

is extra special, as when it's run in the loop, it will sometimes work the first time, but fail the second time. Or it will just fail outright.

Don't really know what makes it work and what doesn't. This just started happening, and the worksheet/table combination seems to only happen to tables I've just inserted recently (not by using VBA).

Comment: you could try to refer with `ListObjects(index)` instead of `ListObjects(name)`

Comment: You'll have to forgive me since I only started working with VBA a few days ago, but is the index just the cell range of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the `Sheets("Mgmt Margin Analysis")` has table named "Table4".  If you are creating the table on runtime, chances are that, it will not be assigned the same name ("Table4") everytime it is created.

Please ensure you assign this name in your code, and do not let Excel to choose the name for you.

Comment: The table is already in the worksheet before the macro is run, but I have been leaving the naming up to Excel...Is it possible that Excel's auto naming system is messing with it when running the macro? I should really name my tables anyways for documentations sake.